# Azure workspace opens browser even when using "use-device-code" flag

Tags: azure, authentication, command-line-interface, workspace

I'm trying to use the Azure CLI `az login` to connect to my workspace. I want to use the `--use-device-code` flag so I can use my secure work laptop to enter the code. The problem is that even when I use this flag, my browser is opened with the Microsoft login screen when I run the `Workspace.from_config` command (yes the config.json file is in the correct directory). This happens for me both on my Ubuntu and Windows installation. When I try running it interactively through the Azure CLI docker image, it does seem to work however. Is there anyone that could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use the --use-device-code flag so I can use my secure work
> laptop to enter the code. The problem is that even when I use this
> flag, my browser is opened with the Microsoft login screen when I run
> the Workspace.from_config

There are different ways to login with azure account by using cli, To not get the Microsoft login screen pop-up you can try the below `cmdlt`

```
az login --username azureusername --password azurepassword
```

Because when we use device code it will ask for entering the code and login as shown here;

```
az login --use-device-code
To sign in, use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code ‘DeviceCode’ to authenticate.
```

For more information please refer this [***Blogpost***](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-log-in-to-the-azure-account-using-az-cli-command-in-powershell) .

Comment: The thing is that it says logging in using the use-device-flag is successful. However, when loading the workspace in my Python script, it will still prompt a web browser. This does not happen when using docker.

Your suggestion isn't working on my end either onfortunately.. I guess the problem is that we're also using 2fa.